# reached end of the file while parsing

Tags: java, parsing

I am new to java programming. I was trying to write a code that convert temperature from Fahrenheit to Celsius or vice versa , and I am getting reached end of the file while parsing error . so what should I do to fix it

```
package fahrenheittocelsius;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Fahrenheittocelsius
{



    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String firstchoice ;
        String ftc ="fahrenheit to celsuis" ;
        String ctf = "celsius to fahrenheit";

        System.out.println("Do you want to convert from  'fahrenheit to celsuis' or 'celsius to fahrenheit' ");

        Scanner firstscan = new Scanner(System.in);


        firstchoice = firstscan.nextLine();

        if (firstchoice.equals(ftc) );
        {




        System.out.println("Write in the temperature in Fahrenheit that you want to convert it to celsius ");

        Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);

        double f ;

        f = scan1.nextDouble();

        double c ;

        c= (5/9.0)* (f-23) ;

        System.out.println("the temperature in celsius is " + c );

        }

         if (firstchoice.equals(ctf) );
        {




        System.out.println("Write in the temperature in celsuis that you want to convert it to fahrenheit ");

        Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);

        double CC ;

        double FF ;

        CC = scan2.nextDouble();

        FF= (CC * 2) + 30 ;

        System.out.println("the temperature in celsius is " + FF);

  }

 }
```

Comment: Please include the full error that you're getting in the question.

Comment: You're missing a closing `}`. If you formatted your code pleasantly, you'd find that easy to spot. If you're not using an IDE or an editor which can format your code for you, indenting it appropriately, I suggest you start right now.

Comment: hi celeo  ,  i am using netbeans and at the last line a red point appear and and it say  reached end of the file while parsing i dont know what it mean and what should i do to fix it...

Comment: jon where should i put the missing }

Comment: Ali, where do you think it should go? Part of learning to program is solving problems. Look for where you've put `{` and figure out where the `}` should go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means you've forgotten a `}` somewhere.

I count 4 opening curly braces, but only 3 closing braces. Look for where you missed one.

Also, remove the semi-colons after your `if` statements.

```
if(someCondition){
    //do stuff
}
```

not

```
if(someCondition);{
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: i did it tene ,  thanks you for your time  and thanks alan for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Your second if doesn't have a closing }

Suggestion also, instead of making the user write Strings, make him write int. 1 for Celsius to Fah, 2 for Fah - Celsius. Switch and cases in a while statement make this type of programs more understandable. You can add a case 0 to exit and end the program.